# MYSQL ERROR: Cannot connect: invalid settings

Tags: php, mysql

I'm Receiving this ERROR on MY SQL :

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings. 
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I tried everything but still getting this error.

here is the ERROR LOG from MYSQL:

```
2017-01-18 14:46:01 10496 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:01 2558 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:01 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:01 10496 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:01 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:01 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:01 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:01 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:01 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:01 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 59818 in the ib_logfiles!<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages <br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] InnoDB: 1 rollback segment(s) are active.<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.26 started; log sequence number 59818<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 1 !!!<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] IPv6 is available.<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';<br><br>
2017-01-18 14:46:02 10496 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.<br><br>
```

And I tried also using NAVICAT and SQLYOG but once I tried to Connect my MYSQL keep on FORCE CLOSE

Any Answer on how to handle this?

Comment: mysql != sql-server

Comment: Well did you make sure you're using the correct credentials? Where is the MySQL instance running and from which location are you trying to connect to it? Did you try the MySQL command line client on the same machine? Did that machine crash or why does the log say the DB wasn't shut down properly? Currently it seems to respond on the localhost IPv6 address only. I'm not sure if there would be a separate message for and IPv4 socket.

Comment: I'm currently using ROOT as my username and I don't have any password set on my database.